# What is a "whisker"?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am revising for algebraic topology and an exercise sheet from class is just weird straight. Here's the problem I don't even know what it means

> Let $X$ be a space. Let $Y$ be a space obtained from $X$ by adding a whisker at $ a \in X$. More formally, $Y$ is the quotient space of the disjoint union $X \cup I$ in which $a \in X$ is identified with $0 \in I$. Prove that inclusion $i:X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence.

What is a whisker. after $20$ years of math I've never heard of that term apart fro "box and whiskers" and it just doesn't make sense to me here. And the "more formally," bit, "$a$ is identified with"? What does it mean "identified with." I think the closest possible meaning would be "defined by" but the $0 \in I$ that follows doesn't make sense if I replace "identified with" by "defined by".

algebraic topology is obscure enough in its own regard and I'm just hoping professors would stop making the problem statement obscure as well. Is anyone familiar with these strange terminologies?Can you explain them to me?

Comment: I think he means whisker as in a piece of hair. He's gluing an interval $I$ to $X$ by gluing the zero end of it to the element $a$. The other end is free, so the interval literally becomes a whisker.

Comment: Are you familiar with the quotient topology?

Comment: It's not a formal term. It just looks like a whisker. A line segment sticking out.

Answer (score 4):

The problem states that we have the space $X\cup I/\sim$, where the equivalence relation is qiven by $a\sim 0$, where $a\in X$ and $0\in I$. What this graphically means is that we add a shape in the form of a hair (or a whisker) to the space $X$. We do this by sticking one end of the hair to the space $X$. Note that you get a homotopy equivalence by "shrinking" the length of the whisker.

Comment: Is the hair or whisker always contractible? When does a whisker imply a homeomorphism?